# Runtime Error: Can anyone help me out? Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error

The following piece of code has some runtime error cannot seem to fix it. Can anyone help?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    no_of_parked_vehicles = int(input())
    list_vehicles = {}
    t = 0
    for i in range(no_of_parked_vehicles):
        vehicleSeq = int(input())
        fourWheeler = input()
        parkedFor = float(input())
        valetParking = input()
        t = t + 1
        parked_vehicle = ParkedVehicle(vehicleSeq, fourWheeler, parkedFor, valetParking)
        list_vehicles[t] = parked_vehicle

    parking_lot = ParkingLot(list_vehicles)

    lot_number = int(input())
    temp =  parking_lot.updateParkedStatus(lot_number)
    charge = parking_lot.getParkingCharges(lot_number)

    if temp == None:
        print("Lot Number Invalid")
    else:
        print(temp[0], temp[1])

    if charge == None:
        print("Lot Number Invalid")
    else:
        print(charge)
```

**The error is:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "Solution.py", line 47, in <module>

    parkedFor = float(input())

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'No'**
```

Comment: please include the inputs you are giving to your program.

Comment: Your code expects a number and you enter 'No', the error message is perfectly explicit - what other question do you have?

Comment: The error is because you are giving a string to  parkedFor = float(input()) , you must only give a number as the input

Comment: Note that `input` takes a parameter, which is the prompt presented to the user. Use it to make things explicit.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are entering text 'No' in the console when you should be entering a float number for the variable parkedFor.

I understand you are miscalculating and you wanted to enter 'No' in the next input for valetParking variable.